# Django makemessages javascript catalog bails on weird error

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-i18n

I issue the following command to translate my javascript texts with django:

```
$ /manage.py makemessages -d djangojs -l fr_CA -e html,py,js --settings=settings.local
```

For several files I keep on getting the following error:

```
> /templates/core/file.html.c:49: warning: unterminated string literal
```

And I assume that it quits on this error as my javascript texts with gettext are never translated. I notice that on files without this warning it seems to work.

I could not for figure at which point it was producing this error, so i went line by line and it seems to have problems with:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        {% include "patients/patient_breakdown_block.html" with page='dashboard' %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Namely the line with the include.

I'm at my wits end trying to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the content of `patients/patient_breakdown_block.html` ?

Comment: Here's the include, http://pastebin.com/BZkc5QCs.

Comment: You're template seems fine. I think your problem lies in the javascript file. Can you paste it too ?